# Edit Form React JS and Add

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I add a record(y record) it's added, but when I'm trying to edit it before I click on submit I want to edit same record. In my case it's add it as a new record(ym record) with updated data, please any help.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the logic you use for Add and update record?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to get RecordID in response  when it was first added to the DB . After that you can simply check if the ID exist then send a update query .

Like that

```
Axios.post('[your route here]',data,[headers]).then((res) = >{
   if(res.status == 200 ){
     recordID =  res.data.recordId;   
  }
 } )
```

And In your backend where you have set the API Code you just need to check if recordID exist already then simply update the record. Else add a new record.

Comment: thx , but i solved it with index instead of the id and it`s worked, appreciate ur answer.